# In pumpAndSettle() in Flutter, how can I specify timeout without also passing in EnginePhase?

Tags: testing, dart, flutter

The pumpAndSettle() [documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetTester/pumpAndSettle.html) says that I can pass in a `timeout`.
I do this via:

```
await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(minutes: 11), 
  EnginePhase.sendSemanticsUpdate, 
  Duration(minutes: 12),
);
```

How do I pass in a timeout without having to also specify the EnginePhase? I just want to use the default EnginePhase.

I tried:

```
await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(minutes: 11), 
  Duration(minutes: 12),
);


await tester.pumpAndSettle([Duration(minutes: 11), 
  Duration(minutes: 12),
]);


await tester.pumpAndSettle(duration: Duration(minutes: 11), 
  timeout: Duration(minutes: 12),
);

await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(minutes: 11), 
  timeout: Duration(minutes: 12),
);
```

What is the name of this syntax, where you have an optional List of inputs in a function? I tried to look it up in Dart syntax but wasn't sure what it was called.

Comment: You can't specify a timeout without EnginePhase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.  `pumpAndSettle` uses [optional *positional* arguments](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#optional-parameters), so you can't specify later arguments without also providing earlier arguments.